# Restore Firebird backup

Tags: sql, firebird, restore

I have a database backup of a Firebird. It has the .bak extension. I would like some help on how to restore this backup in IB Expert or DBeaver. Note: I always see IB Expert backup with GBAK, this is the first time I see .BAK.

Comment: extension of the backup file could be anything the administrator prefers. Firebird doesn't care what the extension of the backup file is.

Comment: Are you sure it is a Firebird backup? If yes, you need to know how it was created: using gbak or nbackup. For gbak, see [Firebird Backup & Restore Utility](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gbak/firebird-gbak.html) or you can just restore like you normally do with IB Expert, for nbackup, see [Firebird’s nbackup tool](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/nbackup/firebird-nbackup.html). As far as I'm aware, DBeaver does not provide support for restoring Firebird gbak or nbackup backups.

Comment: In any case, in its current state your question isn't really answerable.

Comment: 1) try FirstAid of www.ib-aid.com - will it even recognize file format or not ?  2) show first few dozens of bytes of your file as HEX strings. You might switch into hex mode in Lister of tools like Total Commander / Unreal Commander / similar ones. Or in any hex editor (like HxD) - but do NOT save the file in editor by accident, only view - copy - close.  3) try to engage file format recognition tool on your file, like https://www.raymond.cc/blog/what-file-is-that-how-to-identify-unrecognized-files-types-and-format/

Comment: thank you all for the help, i will try to restore